# Capture microphone audio stream in Windows using C

Tags: c, windows, audio, microphone

I'm looking to build a Morse decoder (and eventually a coder) in C.  I'd like to use the audio port as input, and sample the incoming voltage on the port.

How do I go about reading the voltage on a microphone audio port in Windows using C?

Comment: Just be careful with the microphone port - it wasn't designed to handle wild voltages...

Comment: Note, an audio port filters out any DC component. So if you want to input Morse, it must be an oscillating wave, not just an On/Off value. A steady On/Off value will decay to zero within a short time.

Comment: Thanks for the tips...I'm going to be processing about 700Hz and will have devices in line to condition the signal to be sure I won't run into those issues...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplist way is to use the [*waveIn*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452431.aspx) functions provided by the Win32 API.

You can read [Recording and Playing Sound with the Waveform Audio Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446573.aspx) for an overview, or just dive into the [API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940101.aspx).