# how to read from microphone using C

Tags: audio, microphone

I been searching for how to read audio from the microphone using C, i understand how to read a .wav file, do any of you know how to read audio from the microphone in real time.

Comment: On what OS do you want it to work?

Comment: if Windows read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897042/capture-microphone-audio-stream-in-windows-using-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the developer documentation for your operating system.  It is impossible to answer in general because the audio APIs are so different on each platform (DirectSound, ASIO, CoreAudio, ALSA, OSS, Jack, ...)